# How to disable SuggestBox in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using SuggestBox to let user to select values. 
But however when there is only one value in the list, I am setting the value in the SuggestBox and I want this field to be non-editable.

I am trying below things, but now the component is not visible on UI.

```
sgstBox.getTextBox().setEnabled(false);
```

this is not working either

```
sgstBox.getTextBox().setReadOnly(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two not tested solutions [found on Google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/86847d84f4b1cf2b):

```
public static void setEnabled(SuggestBox sb,boolean enabled) {
                DOM.setElementPropertyBoolean(sb.getElement(), "disabled", !enabled);
}
```

and

```
//pass in your own TextBox when you construct the SB:

TextBox tb = new TextBox();
SuggestBox sb = new SuggestBox(oracle, tb);

//...and later disable the TextBox:

tb.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Handling DOM element is working fine. Didn't try second one.
Thank you.